# Why can't I use builtin for classes that overload subsref?

Tags: oop, matlab, overriding, built-in

I would like to overload only one type of subsref calls (the '()' type) for a particular class and leave any other calls to Matlab's built in subsref -- specifically, I want Matlab to handle property/method access via the '.' type.  But, it seems like Matlab's 'builtin' function doesn't work when subsref is overloaded in a class.

Consider this class:

```
classdef TestBuiltIn
    properties
        testprop = 'This is the built in method';
    end

    methods
        function v = subsref(this, s)
            disp('This is the overloaded method');
        end
    end
end
```

To use the overloaded subsref method, I do this:

```
t = TestBuiltIn;
t.testprop
    >> This is the overloaded method
```

That's as expected.  But now I want to call Matlab's built in subsref method.  To make sure I'm doing things right, first I try out a similar call on a struct:

```
x.testprop = 'Accessed correctly';
s.type = '.';
s.subs = 'testprop';
builtin('subsref', x, s)
    >> Accessed correctly
```

That's as expected as well.  But, when I try the same method on TestBuiltIn:

```
builtin('subsref', t, s)
    >> This is the overloaded method
```

...Matlab calls the overloaded method rather than the built in method.  Why does Matlab call the *overloaded* method when I requested that it call the *builtin* method?

UPDATE:
In response to @Andrew Janke's answer, that solution almost works but doesn't quite.  Consider this class:

```
classdef TestIndexing
    properties
        prop1
        child
    end

    methods
        function this = TestIndexing(n)
            if nargin==0
                n = 1;
            end

            this.prop1 = n;
            if n<2
                this.child = TestIndexing(n+1);
            else
                this.child = ['child on instance ' num2str(n)];
            end
        end

        function v = subsref(this, s)
            if strcmp(s(1).type, '()')
                v = 'overloaded method';
            else
                v = builtin('subsref', this, s);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

All of this works:

```
t = TestIndexing;
t(1)
    >> overloaded method
t.prop1
    >> 1
t.child
    >> [TestIndexing instance]
t.child.prop1
    >> 2
```

But this doesn't work; it uses the built in subsref for the child rather than the overloaded subsref:

```
t.child(1)
    >> [TestIndexing instance]
```

Note that the above behavior is inconsistent with both of these behaviors (which are as expected):

```
tc = t.child;
tc(1)
    >> overloaded method

x.child = t.child;
x.child(1)
    >> overloaded method
```

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand, but I think that first the builtin function is called, and then in that call the overloading method is called. If possible put a breakpoint in a usefull spot.

Comment: Something completely different: I hope you just try to do this out of personal interest, as for most problems overloading subsref may not be the nicest solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the builtin function being called first -- if that were hypothetically the case (not sure how, but say), I think I would need to set a breakpoint inside Matlab's built in subsref function to verify.  But that's a native function rather than an m function, so I can't put a breakpoint there.

Comment: What I really want to do is change the () indexing behavior of my class, just like Matlab's griddedInterpolant class does.  But I don't want to have to rewrite the {} and . referencing behaviors from scratch.  Unfortunately, this question leads me to believe that it is impossible to change one behavior without re-implementing the other behaviors from scratch as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, IIRC. To change `()` but not `{}` and '.', write your `subsref` method to pass those other cases along to the builtin subsref from within your overloaded subsref, instead of trying to explicitly call the builtin from outside.

```
function B = subsref(A, S)
    % Handle the first indexing on your obj itself
    switch S(1).type
        case '()'
            B = % ... do your custom "()" behavior ...
        otherwise
            % Enable normal "." and "{}" behavior
            B = builtin('subsref', A, S(1))
        end
    end
    % Handle "chaining" (not sure this part is fully correct; it is tricky)
    orig_B = B; % hold on to a copy for debugging purposes
    if numel(S) > 1
        B = subsref(B, S(2:end)); % regular call, not "builtin", to support overrides
    end
end
```

(And if that `builtin` call doesn't work, you can just put in cases that use `.` and `{}` directly, because the `subsref` overload is ignored inside the class definition.)

To make it fully functional, you may need to change B to a varargout, and add chaining behavior in to the "()" case.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but not quite -- please see the update in my question

Comment: What's going on there is that in Matlab, an expression with multiple indexing like `foo.bar.baz(3)`, instead of being evaluated in steps like doing `foo.bar` and then passing the result to `.baz` and then passing that result to `(3)`, will parse up the entire expression and pass it in a single call to subsref. (This is nonintuitive.) So your `subsref` needs to look at S, handle S(1), and then handle "chaining" behavior by manually passing the results along with `S(2:end)` along to another call of `subsref`, which will then pick up the overloaded method.

Comment: I've modified my example code to show "chaining" behavior. It's a bit tricky and I can't test it for correctness because I don't have Matlab right now (sorry), but this is basically what you need to do.

Comment: (Note that the important part is that the chained `subsref` call is a regular `subsref()` call, not via builtin. Doing the entire thing with a single builtin call will ignore (some of) the overriden methods on intermediate expression results, which looks like what you got in your "update" examples.)

Comment: P.S. Be patient; working with `subsref`, `subsasgn`, and their friends really is difficult, and a lot of work to get fully correct. Experiment, and give the documentation a good thorough reread or two.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the explanation given on the [Mathworks board](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/73430-why-can-t-i-use-builtin-for-classes-that-overload-subsref), builtin only works from within an overloaded method to access the pre-existing (built in) method.

Overloading a method in Matlab effectively shadows the built in implementation from *everything* except the method doing the shadowing, and the method doing the shadowing must use builtin to access the built in implementation instead of recursing into itself.

Answer (score 0):

In general. You should use `builtin(m,s)` inside the function that is been overloaded. This is specified clearly in MATLAB documentation.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html

> builtin(function,x1,...,xn) executes the built-in function with the
>   input arguments x1 through xn. Use builtin to execute the original
>   built-in from within a method that overloads the function. To work
>   properly, you must never overload builtin.

Consider this code:

```
classdef TestBuiltIn
    properties
        testprop = 'This is the built in method';
        testprop2 = 'This is the derived subsref ';
    end
    methods

        function v = subsref(m, s)
            disp('enter subsref no matter how!');
            v = builtin('subsref',m, s);
        end
    end
end
```

and test command

```
clear;
t = TestBuiltIn;
builtin('subsref', t, s)
s.type = '.';
s.subs = 'testprop';
s2 = s;
s2.subs = 'testprop2';

>> builtin('subsref', t, s1)

enter subsref no matter how!

ans =

This is the derived subsref 

>> builtin('subsref', t, s)
enter subsref no matter how!

ans =

This is the built in method
```

Answer (score 0):

In your updated version of this problem, when you call `t.child(1)`, the `subsref` function will receive argument `s` with `s(1).type='.', s(1).subs='child'` and `s(2).type='()', s(2).subs='1'`.  The evaluation of this expression is not in a step-by-step manner, as [Andrew Janke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105904/andrew-janke) mentioned in his answer. As a result, when overriding `subsref`, you should handle this operation chain, by first processing the '.' operator. Here is a incomplete example for your case,

```
function v = subsref(this, s)
    switch s(1).type
       case '.'
           member = s(1).subs;
           if ismethod(this, member)
               % invoke builtin function to access method member
               % there is issue about the number of output arguments
               v = builtin('subsref',this,s);
           elseif isprop(this, member) % property
               if length(s) == 1
                   % invoke builtin function to access method member
                   v = builtin('subsref', this, s);
               elseif length(s) == 2 && strcmp(s(2).type,'()')
                   % this is where you evaluate 'tc.child(1)'
               else
                   % add other cases when you need, otherwise calling builtin
               end
           else
               % handling error.
           end
       case '()'
           % this is where you evaluate 't(1)'
           % you may need to handle something like 't(1).prop1', like the '.' case
       otherwise
           % by default, calling the builtin.
    end
end
```

You can also find a detailed code sample and instruction at [Code Patterns for subsref and subsasgn Methods](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html).

One more thing you may need to know, is that *method members* in this class will also be invoked through `subsref` with '.' operation. Look at this subject [subsref on classes: how to dispatch methods?](https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/236103), you will find that the `builtin` function has no return value (since the invoked method has no return value). However, the return value of `builtin` is assigned to `v`(even though `v` is replaced by `varargout`), which is an obvious error. The author also gives a temporary solution by using `try ... catch` to resolve this error.