# Storing and accessing a piecewise interpolant using a single handle

Tags: matlab, interpolation, handle, curve-fitting, piecewise

I have a dataset containing two vectors of points, `X` and `Y` that represents measurements of an "exponential-like" phenomenon (i.e. `Y = A*exp(b*x)`). When fitting it with an exponential equation I'm getting a *nice-looking* fit, but when I'm using it to compute things it turns out that the fit is not quite as accurate as I would hope.

Currently my most promising idea is a piecewise exponential fit (taking about 6 `(x,y)` pairs each time), which seems to provide better results in cases I tested manually. Here's a diagram to illustrate what I mean to do:

```
// Assuming a window of size WS=4:
 - - - - - - - - - - - -  //the entire X span of the data
[- - - -]- - // the fit that should be evaluated for X(1)<= x < X(floor(WS/2)+1)
 -[- - - -]- // the fit that should be evaluated for X(3)<= x < X(4)
...
 - - - - - -[- - - -]- - // X(8)<= x < X(9)
... //and so on
```

#### Some Considerations:

- I considered filtering the data before fitting, but this is tricky since I don't really know anything about the type of noise it contains.
- I would like the piecewise fit (including all different cases) to be accessible using a single function handle. It's very similar to MATLAB's [Shape-preserving "PCHIP" interpolant](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/interpolants.html#bsz6baz), only that it should use an exponential function instead.
- The creation of the fit does not need to happen during the runtime of another code. I even prefer to create it separately.
- I'm not worried about the potential unsmoothness of the final function.
- The only way of going about this I could think of is defining an `.m` file as explained in [Fit a Curve Defined by a File](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#example_4), but that would require manually writing conditions for almost as many cases as I have points (or obviously write a code that generates this code for me, which is also a considerable effort).

#### Relevant code snippets:

```
clear variables; clc;
%% // Definitions
CONSTS.N_PARAMETERS_IN_MODEL = 2; %// For the model y = A*exp(B*x);
CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE = 4; 
assert(~mod(CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE,2) && CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE>0,...
    'WINDOW_SIZE should be a natural even number.');
%% // Example Data
X = [0.002723682418630,0.002687088539567,0.002634005004610,0.002582978173834,...
     0.002530684550171,0.002462144527884,0.002397219225698,0.002341097974950,...
     0.002287544321171,0.002238889510803]';
Y = [0.178923076435990,0.213320004768074,0.263918364216839,0.324208349386613,...
     0.394340431220509,0.511466688684182,0.671285738221314,0.843849959919278,...
     1.070756756433334,1.292800046096531]';
assert(CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE <= length(X),...
    'WINDOW_SIZE cannot be larger than the amount of points.');
X = flipud(X); Y = flipud(Y); % ascending sorting is needed later for histc
%% // Initialization
nFits = length(X)-CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE+1;
coeffMat(nFits,CONSTS.N_PARAMETERS_IN_MODEL) = 0; %// Preallocation
ft = fittype( 'exp1' );
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
%% // Populate coefficient matrix
for ind1 = 1:nFits
    [xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(...
        X(ind1:ind1+CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE-1),Y(ind1:ind1+CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE-1));
    %// Fit model to data:
    fitresult = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
    %// Save coefficients:
    coeffMat(ind1,:) = coeffvalues(fitresult);
end
clear ft opts ind1 xData yData fitresult ans
%% // Get the transition points
xTrans = [-inf; X(CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE/2+1:end-CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE/2); inf];
```

At this point, `xTrans` and `coeffMat` contain all the required information to evaluate the fits. To show this we can look at a vector of some test data:

```
testPts = [X(1), X(1)/2, mean(X(4:5)), X(CONSTS.WINDOW_SIZE)*1.01,2*X(end)];
```

...and finally the following should roughly happen internally within the handle:

```
%% // Get the correct fit# to be evaluated:
if ~isempty(xTrans) %// The case of nFits==1
    rightFit = find(histc(testPts(3),xTrans));
else
    rightFit = 1;
end
%% // Actually evaluate the right fit
f = @(x,A,B)A*exp(B*x);
yy = f(testPts(3),coeffMat(rightFit,1),coeffMat(rightFit,2));
```

**And so my problem is** how to hold that last bit (along with all the fit coefficients) inside a single handle, that accepts an **arbitrarily-sized input** of points to interpolate on?

#### Related resources:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/16777921/matlab-curve-fitting-exponential-vs-linear/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777921/matlab-curve-fitting-exponential-vs-linear/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not all clear but why not to puts things into a class ?

```
classdef Piecewise < handle

    methods

        % Construction
        function [this] = Piecewise(xmeas, ymeas)
            ... here compute xTrans and coeffMat...
        end

        % Interpolation
        function [yinterp] = Evaluate(xinterp)
            ... Here use previously computed xTrans and coeffMat ...
        end
    end

    properties(SetAccess=Private, GetAccess=Private)
        xTrans;
        coeffMat;
    end

end
```

In this way you can prcompute `xTrans` vector and `coeffMat` matrix during construction and then later reuse these properties when you need to evaluate interpolant at `xinterp` values in `Evaluate` method.

```
% The real measured data
xmeas = ...
ymeas = ...

% Build piecewise interpolation object
piecewise = Piecewise(x,meas, ymeas);

% Rebuild curve at any new positions
xinterp = ...
yinterp = piecewise.Evaluate(xinterp);
```

**Function like syntax**

If you truly prefer to have function-handle like syntax, you can still **internally** use above `Piecewise` object and add extra **static** method to return it as a function handle:

```
classdef Piecewise < handle

    ... see code above...

    methods(Static=true)
        function [f] = MakeHandle(xmeas, ymeas)
        %[
            obj = Piecewise(xmeas, ymeas);
            f = @(x)obj.Evaluate(x);
        %]
    end

end
```

This can be used like this:

```
f = Piecewise.MakeHandle(xmeas, ymeas);
yinterp = f(xinterp);
```

*PS1: You can later put `Evaluate` and `Piecewise` constructor methods as private if you absolutely wanna to force this syntax.*

*PS2: To fully hide object oriented design, you can turn `MakeHandle` into a fully classic routine (will work the same as if static and users won't have to type `Piecewise.` in front of `MakeHandle`).*

**A last solution without oop**

Put everything in a single .m file :

```
function [f] = MakeHandle(xmeas, ymeas)
    ... Here compute xTrans and coeffMat ...
    f = @(x)compute(x, xTrans, coeffMat);% Passing xTrans/coeffMatt as hidden parameters
end
function [yinterp] = compute(xinterp, xTrans, coeffMat)
    ... do interpolation here...
 end
```

Comment: Why not? No reason. But to make it work like I want, I would need to extend `subsref` instead of creating the method `Evaluate`.

Comment: @Dev-iL ... It is possible to redefine `subsref` within the class ... Guess you would like to have a syntax like `piecewise(xinterp)`, right ?

Comment: Precisely - see the 2nd consideration I mentioned. I'm aware that it's possible within a class. If you could add that bit I would be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @Dev-iL I edited my answer for a 'function-handle' like syntax.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll add the subsref version later.

Comment: @Dev-iL Well I may be not fully inline with what you have in mind but I quite discourage you to use `subsref`, *which normally is a coordinate indexer*, as a method accepting double-vector (everybody that will read-back your code will become crasy trying to understand). Why 'function-like' syntax I added isn't ok for what you want ?

Comment: The `subsref` "trick" is a practice employed by MATLAB quite officialy - see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/a-polynomial-class-1.html#f3-62469 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of CitizenInsane's answer, the following is an alternative approach that allows a "`handle`-y" access to the inner `Evaluate` function.

```
    function b = subsref(this,s)
       switch s(1).type
          case '()'
             xval = s.subs{:};
             b = this.Evaluate(xval);
          otherwise %// Fallback to the default behavior for '.' and '{}':
             builtin('subsref',this,s);
       end
    end
```

References: [docs1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/a-polynomial-class-1.html#f3-29093), [docs2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html), [docs3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html), [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198244/why-cant-i-use-builtin-for-classes-that-overload-subsref)

P.S. [docs2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html) is referenced because I initially tried to do `subsref@handle` (which is calling the superclass method, as one would expect in OOP when overriding methods in a subclass), but this doesn't work in MATLAB, which instead requires `builtin()` to achieve the same functionality.